# How to enter dollar symbol in HP Officejet 4500 Wireless?

Tags: network-printer

I recently bought the [HP Officejet 4500 Wirless Printer](http://www.shopping.hp.com/product/printer/Officejet/1/storefronts/CB867A%2523B1H). I'm trying to connect it to my wireless network but I'm unable to enter a dollar symbol which I need for my password. Does anyone know how I can enter this?

Thanks!

Comment: There should be a way to set it up in Windows using the HP solution Center Software > Settings > Network Settings, I assume you are trying to enter it on the printer interface?

Comment: Yes, that's right i was trying to use the keypad on the device itself. I'll try it through the computer when I get a chance. Thanks for the advice!